# Is there a way to make non-transactionl connections chuck out an exception?

Tags: java, oracle, gradle, transactions, dbunit

Problem: MASSIVE build with legacy dbUnit... Except we need it to run integration tests in parallel. Gradle is the build environment. Hundreds of sub-projects. Java is the language.

I've been wrapping all the data sources with TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy and this has helped significantly, however we still get failures when running in parallel. Another symptom is that if you kill the build, your database must be re-built. I assume that this is because something non-transactional gets no chance to do cleanup.

Possibilities I can think of are:

1. Somewhere there is one or more non-transactional tests that need to be annotated as Transactional. If this is the case, then it should mean there are 2 or 3 needles in this haystack and they will be tough to find, by definition.
2. Somewhere I missed wrapping a data source. I've been doing global searches but it's been hard to find. For example, what if it's not named dataSource like all the others?  What if it doesn't use Apache's BasicDataSource like all the others?

Is it possible to make any sort of non-transactional activity an epic and immediate fail? This might help me narrow it down to specific components. I've gotten pretty far but I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: In Oracle, there is no such thing as a non-transactional connection so you can't put any hooks there.  Your Java frameworks are just simulating "non-transactional" operations by running each statement in their own transaction.  I'm not sure whether you are getting failures because the "non-transactional" abstraction is leaky or not (I'm not sure that I fully understand the nature of the failures that you're seeing).

Comment: I'm seeing things like integrity constraint violations when the same key is used by different test suites. Doesn't happen when run in series. Doh!! Just found 2 more data sources that need to be wrapped.